# beginner C "==" always evaluates to false

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, conditional-statements

Just a beginner question. I tried to find an answer to this but I couldn't.

Why

```
for (int i = 0;i==10;++i) {
/* body of the for loop */
}
```

Never executes the body of the for loop? but this one works?

```
for (int i = 0;i<=10;++i) {
/* body of the for loop */
}
```

The (i==0) should be a boolean expression evaluating to false if i==0, right?
This perfectly works if I put that expression in an if statement like

```
for(int i=10;;++i) {
if (i==10) break;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It only has to evaluate to false once for the loop to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; <condition>;++i) {
/* body of the for loop */
}
```

The key to understanding this is that the body executes every time the *condition* evaluates to TRUE. In your example, it evaluates to FALSE first time itself, and hence nothing executes.

In your second example, *condition* is omitted. Which means the body executes forever, until you break out of it. Which you do when i == 10. Hence the body executes 10 times.

Comment: Your answer has the same problem Aidan's did. Your phrasing is misleading. Its not "every time the ...." because if it was, the asker's loop would work for every time `x == 10`. More accurately, the loop runs "as long as" or "while" contition is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

C++ 101: The middle condition must be true for the loop to continue.

Answer (score 2):

A for loop basically means to continue as long as the middle condition is true.

So the loop, in this case will only continue when i==10. Which it isn't therefore it stops.

Answer (score 1):

Because the condition in your first loop says only to increment when `i` is equal to to 10. You set `i` to 0, so it will never increment because it has no way of getting there.

The second one works because you say `i` is equal to 0, and while `i` is less than or equal to 10, it is incremented by 1. 0 is less than 10, but not equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

`for(;true;)

{

        //this is infinite loop

}`

Condition should be true in order to enter into the loop,
in your case i==10 returns false hence it does not enter into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0;i==10;++i) {
         /* body of the for loop */
        }
```

for this code i=0 initially, when condition is checked (i==10) it results in false so loop will not iterate.

Check carefully for what values of i you want to run the loop.

for example your loop may be

```
     for (int i = 0;i<=10;++i) {
       /* body of the for loop */
      }
```

the body of loop will iterate from 0 to 10 including both.